# When i save as pdf in python tkinter it's showing error

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to save my document as pdf but when i save as pdf its save successfully but showing error when i try to open pdf file

```
def save_file(event = None):
       global text_url
       try:
          if text_url:
             content = str(text_editor.get(1.0,tk.END))
             with open(text_url,"w",encoding="utf-8") as for_read:
                for_read.write(content)
          else:
             text_url=filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode = "w",defaultextension="txt",filetypes=(("Text file","*.txt"),("All files","*.*"),("PDF","*.pdf")))
             conrent2 = text_editor.get(1.0,tk.END)
             text_url.write(content2)
             text_url.close()
       except:
             return
```

Comment: What's the error? Is it a valid pdf file?

Comment: Say `except Exception as e:    print(e)` and update the Q with it, or if its some-other error then please elaborate. I think you cant just create a pdf like this, you have to use some python-pdf integration library to write to a pdf file.

Comment: Please take the time to read this and update your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Writing text to a file with a .PDF extension does not make it a PDF file - it's just a badly-named text file.